# How to avoid unnecessary br tags when using table tag in nl2br?

Tags: javascript, php, html, nl2br

I have a variable text that sometimes contains plain text or sometimes codes and sometimes tables.

I want to minimize the HTML tags in the database, so I didn't use `pre` tag in `table` and `text` and used only in the codes (space preservation is not required in other two cases).

Now I'm stuck in a problem where I have `tables` as my data which is passing through `nl2br` that causing the following output in my source codes.

```
<table><br />
    <thead><br />
        <tr><br />
            <th>Operator</th><br />
            <th>Left</th><br />
            <th>Right</th><br />
            <th>Remark</th><br />
        </tr><br />
    </thead><br />
    <tbody><br />
        <tr><br />
            <td>/</td><br />
            <td>10</td><br />
            <td>5 or 5 / 2 / 1</td><br />
            <td>Left operand is unambiguous, right is not</td><br />
        </tr><br />
        <tr><br />
            <td>/</td><br />
            <td>5 or 10 / 5</td><br />
            <td>2 or 2 / 1<td><br />
            <td>Both left and right are ambiguous</td><br />
        </tr><br />
        <tr><br />
            <td>/</td><br />
            <td>2 or 10 / 5 / 2</td><br />
            <td>1</td><br />
            <td>Right operand is unambiguous and left is not</td><br />
        </tr><br />
    </tbody><br />
</table><br />
```

But in chrome developer's tools, it is showing something different than this.

```
</p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> 
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<table class="rembr">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Operator</th>
            <th>Left</th>
            <th>Right</th>
            <th>Remark</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>/</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>5 or 5 / 2 / 1</td>
            <td>Left operand is unambiguous, right is not</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>/</td>
            <td>5 or 10 / 5</td>
            <td>2 or 2 / 1</td><td>
            </td><td>Both left and right are ambiguous</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>/</td>
            <td>2 or 10 / 5 / 2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Right operand is unambiguous and left is not</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><br>
```

I did not understand this behavior why different outputs for the same page.

Well, for now, I want to know how can I use table tag in `nl2br` without having the `br` after every `table` tag?

Comment: You get that in Chromes inspector since it tries to fix the invalid HTML for you. If you right click on the page and look at "view source", you will get the same result as in other browsers. Regarding not adding `<br />` for the tables, don't run it though `nl2br()`. You should know what format the data in your table contains. Either allow HTML or don't. Data integrity and consistency is important in the long run.

Comment: Dom parsers like DomDocument will offer the best stability in handling valid html.  Regex should only be plan B.  Might you have a mix of table and non-table data?  Can you just check the string in advance?  Stripping out the br tags that follow a closing table structure tag, will _look_ hacky. ...adding too much and then mopping up is not pretty coding.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what is the **invalid HTML* as you said *You get that in Chromes inspector since it tries to fix the invalid HTML*

Comment: Having `<br />` after `table`, `thead`, `tbody` `tr`, `th` and `td`. Since those tags belong together, having other HTML-tags between them is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling days, I found a perfect solution for this.  `pre-wrap`.

It will preserve white-spaces and new lines but wrap the word when overflow the text.

So,

```
div{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```